# Printing an Array that Includes Inheritance members?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I have this issue with my code.
I create a class Employee with two instance variables:

```
private String name, department;
```

And afterwards I create another class called Tradesman whichc is an extension of Employee, but with one extra instance variable:

```
private String trade;
```

Now what I did is I created a `print()` method that will: A) in Employee class, print the *name* and *department*. B) same method used in Employee, will be created in Tradesman (thus overriding it) that will print extra one element which is the *trade*. Now the thing is that I create another class called *Staff* which will contain an array of type `Object` of some elements, and I have to implement a `hire()` method, `fire()` method and a `put()` method which will print the entire array. Everything is cool and wicked up till the moment of printing. I'm struggling with how to print it, since I have `print()` method for each class but it must be dependedn on the type... If i cast the method to *Employee* I will lose the *trade* element of Tradesman Class, ex:

```
void put(){
    for (Object a:objArray){
        ((Employee)a).print();
    }
}
```

Which is WRONG. Cause if I hire a Tradesman, this method won't print the Trade. How to deal with this problem? Thanks in advance! Cheers ^^

Comment: *"Cause if I hire a Tradesman, this method won't print the Trade"* You're wrong, it will. Anyway, if all your array objects are Employee, just use an Employee[] instead of Object[]

Comment: To start, you shouldn't use an array of `Object`. Use `Employee[]` instead.

Comment: I want to implement an array of both Tradesman and Employee...

Comment: One array that will contain both, Tradesman and Employee combined.

Comment: You should have `Tradesman` and `Employee` both inherit from a common base class, such as `Worker`, and then use `Worker[]`. Handling this situation is the entire point of inheritance.

Comment: @chrylis Tradesman already extends Employee.

Comment: and what moskit0 says exactly does that. Tradesman indeed is an Employee, and casting a Tradesman to a Employee wont change the behaviour of the print method.

Comment: If `Tradesman` extends `Employee`, you can put instances of it in an `Employee[]`. Just like you can put them in an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cause if I hire a Tradesman, this method won't print the Trade"

You're wrong, it will. If `Employee` is actually a `Tradesman`, calling `print()` will call `Tradesman.print()`. If it's overriden, then the overriding method will be called. If all your array objects are `Employee`, just use an `Employee[]` instead of `Object[]` so you don't have to do that useless casting.

> "I want to implement an array of both Tradesman and Employee... One array that will contain both, Tradesman and Employee combined."

`Employee[]` will hold both since a `Tradesman` is an `Employee`. Also in Java I suggest you work with a `List` (`List<Employee>` in your case), it's more manageable than an array.

Comment: I know about the Lists but it's an exercise for my University assignment and I have to use an array :/
But other than that Thank you! You were right :D
I didn't notice it was printing the trade ^^

Comment: Ok then just use arrays, but in real life use `List`! :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you cast a `Tradesman` to `Employee` the underlying object will still be of type `Tradesman` and use the overridden `print` method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Employee {
  String name,department;

  public Employee(String name, String department) {
   this.name = name;
   this.department = department;
  }

  public void print() {
   System.out.println("Name: " + this.name);
   System.out.println("Department: " + this.department);
  }
}

class Tradesman extends Employee {

  String trade;

  public Tradesman(String name, String department, String trade) {
   super(name,department);
   this.trade = trade;
  }

 public void print() {
   super.print();
   System.out.println("Trade: " + this.trade);

 }
}

class Staff {

  ArrayList<Employee> empArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();

  public void put() {
    for(Employee emp : empArray) {
     emp.print();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Staff s = new Staff();
    s.empArray.add(new Employee("John","Sales"));
    s.empArray.add(new Tradesman("Jacob","Sales","Computers"));

    s.put();
 }

}
```